# Use the content of a dynamic html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have dynamically updated the content of my html table.
Now when i try to access all buttons in that table using javascript,
i receive an empty list. But if i add to that table an event listener such as on mouse over, it returns me all the buttons. What can i do to be able to have all the buttons once the Dom loaded?

```
//build list of booking
async function get_booking() {
    let res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/booking/today/');
    let data = await res.json();


    //build table
    const len = data.length;
    if (len > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML += `
            <tr>
                <td>${data[i].id}</td>
                <td data-agent ="${data[i].coy}" >${data[i].name}</t>
                <td data-trip="${data[i].trip}">${data[i].trip}</td>
                <td data-busstop="${data[i].bus_stop}" >${data[i].bus_stop}</td>
                <td data-startdate="${data[i].start_date}">${data[i].start_date}</td>
                <td data-end="${data[i].end_date}">${data[i].end_date}</td>
                <td data-departure="${data[i].departure}">${data[i].departure}</td>
                <td><button class="update" data-booking="${data[i].id}" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></td>
            </tr>`;
        }
    }

}
```

//use the content of the table

```
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
const btns = tbody.querySelectorAll('button');
```

Comment: please post the actual code, you are never calling `get_booking`

Comment: call the `tbody.querySelectorAll('button');` whenever you want to access the buttons, instead of relying on the initial call. Or make `btns` editable (*use `let`*), and update it at the end of `get_booking`

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    let tb = document.querySelector('tbody');
    tb.addEventListener('', () => {
        console.log(tb.querySelectorAll('button'));

    })
    console.log(tb.rows);
    //get all booking created today
    get_booking();
}

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    const tb = document.querySelector('tbody');
    let btns = tb.querySelectorAll('button');

    //get all booking created today
    get_booking();
    btns = tb.querySelectorAll('button');


    console.log(btns);} Gabriele Petrioli, Is it this way?

Comment: it's still giving me an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see where you are using the querySelectorAll. It is likely being called before get_booking() is finished. Perhaps you could call it at the end of get_booking().

I also advise you use a class to find the buttons, that way any other buttons added to the table later will not accidentally be included.

Lastly, you don't need to check the length of your data, if the length is zero, the for loop will simply never execute.

```js
// build list of booking
async function get_booking() {
    let res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/booking/today/');
    let data = await res.json();

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML += `
            <tr>
                <td>${data[i].id}</td>
                <td data-agent ="${data[i].coy}" >${data[i].name}</t>
                <td data-trip="${data[i].trip}">${data[i].trip}</td>
                <td data-busstop="${data[i].bus_stop}" >${data[i].bus_stop}</td>
                <td data-startdate="${data[i].start_date}">${data[i].start_date}</td>
                <td data-end="${data[i].end_date}">${data[i].end_date}</td>
                <td data-departure="${data[i].departure}">${data[i].departure}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="update specialButton"
                            data-booking="${data[i].id}" type="submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>`;
    }
}

var btns = tbody.querySelectorAll('.specialButton');
```